# Pass Information to VB Program

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, parameters

I am making a download manager in VB 2010. I need to be able to pass the download link from an HTML page to the VB Application. This is what i think i need to do in the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="downloadmanager.application?url=http://example.com/example.exe">Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how i could do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can either create a browser plugin to manage the link tracking, or register your own protocol: 
`mydownloadmanager://download?url=http://example.com/example.exe`

check

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/10/19/register-a-custom-url-protocol-handler.aspx